# The C++ Programming Language 4th Edition Bjarne Stroustrup - Assert example

Tags: c++

I read this book: The C++ Programming Language 4th Edition Bjarne Stroustrup. There is this example:

```
namespace Assert {

enum class Mode { throw_, terminate_, ignore_ };

constexpr Mode current_mode = Mode::throw_;
constexpr int current_level = 0;
constexpr int default_level = 1;

constexpr bool level(int n)
{
    return n<=current_level;
}

struct Error : runtime_error {
    Error(const string& p) : runtime_error(p) {}
};

string compose(const char* file, int line, const string& message)
{
    ostringstream os("(");
    os << file << "," << line << "):" << message;
    return os.str();
}

template<bool condition = level(default_level), class Except = Error>
void dynamic(bool assertion, const string& message ="Asser t::dynamic failed")
{
    if (assertion)
        return;
    if (current_mode == Mode::throw_)
        throw Except{message};
    if (current_mode == Mode::terminate_)
        std::terminate();
}

template<>
void dynamic<false ,Error>(bool, const string&) // do nothing
{
}

void dynamic(bool b, const string& s) // default action
{
    dynamic<true ,Error>(b,s);
}

void dynamic(bool b) // default message
{
    dynamic<true ,Error>(b);
}

}
```

I have a question about this code:

```
void dynamic(bool b, const string& s) // default action
{
    dynamic<true ,Error>(b,s);
}
```

It is used when we call this in for example this way:

```
Assert::dynamic(true, "test");
```

But there is a problem in my opinion. Is it ignore the `current_level` value or am I wrong? In this case we always throw exceptions, even if `current_level` should block it.
Is there problem with this example or I don't understand it?

Comment: Please re-phrase your question text. It's unclear what you are asking. Use google translate if English is not your native language.

Comment: It ignores, and then it calls the version with `<>`. The version with `<>` (templated) does not ignore `current_mode` or `default_level`.

Comment: Please explain what the code is supposed to do. Questions are supposed to be self-contained, not relying on external sources to be answerable. Without something saying how the code is supposed to work, we can only assume that it does work as intended.

Comment: But we set values for this template: `dynamic<true ,Error>(b,s);`. So instead of using this: `bool condition = level(default_level)` we set it always for true. Right?

Comment: It should throw a exception only if current level is higher than default level and assertion is false. I think there is a mistake in this book, but I am not sure, and this is why I am asking :)

Comment: Why not write a few tests? Can you not test the thing you are worried about?